# SSRS: repeat tablix left-most row group value on each row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tablix in an SSRS 2008 report.  It has two-level row groupings, and I'd like the value for the left-most grouping to continue to be displayed on each row.  Eg, I get this:

```
group1  subgroup1  500.00
        subgroup2  250.00
```

... but I'd prefer...

```
group1  subgroup1  500.00
group1  subgroup2  500.00
```

I can't seem to find the option for this.  Is it a strange thing to want?

Thank you,
Bill

Answer (score 18):

You can simply edit the upper reporting level, to be grouping on both groups at the same time, this will cause your desired behaviour.

I had to resort to this solution once, where "hide duplicates" didn't seem to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Hide duplicates did not work for me. But I added both fields to the initial grouping, and the 2nd grouing has the 2nd field again... this seems to work.

Comment: This worked for me. In the above question, you would click the little down arrow to the right of the parent group in the Row Groups window then choose Group Properties, then click Add under Group expressions and choose the name of the sub group and click OK.

Answer (score 5):

It's so simple...you have to right click on the cell in the DATA area (ex. where is displayed the value 500) and to click add COLUMN on the left. After this change the value in the new cell with the label field (subgorup1), also do this for the others columns that you want to add, but remember to do it from the DATA area. when you finish, delete the columns out of the data area, but keep the row groups. nice try!

Comment: Best answer, took me 10 seconds:)

Comment: Will the solution works if we have toggle enabled on the main group ?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, what I've found to be a good way of determining whether or not the repeated values of a group would show up in a SSRS report, is to create the Groups and build your report based on the groupings.  Secondly, take the groups fields and duplicate the column to the right hand side of the report.  Making sure that you've included all the columns needed and totals are correct; delete the grouped columns.  When you do this, you will get a popup asking if you want to delete the group or just the columns, chose columns - this will keep the format of the initial report and keep all of the total line as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the row in question, there is a field called Hide Duplicates. Set this to nothing (null, space, etc) That should return the values you want.

Comment: Hide Duplicates "None" seems to be the default.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and I solved it really easily.

It seems you have two row groups, by group and by subgroup.

What you have to do is to select the first column and group by group and by subgroup and remove the grouping by subgroup.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Put `ROW_NUMBER()` OVER `(ORDER BY name ASC) AS Row#` in each query as a serial number and hide the row in the SSRS Report.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15