# Remove Tablix Static Columns Row Groups in SSRS

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, static, pivot

I have a report in SSRS that uses a matrix with static columns.
Here are the static columns:

[image]

After generating the report, the rows with same values end up being grouped together:

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of these groups? I'd rather the values be repeated for each row, so it looks more like an excel sheet.

Here is a better picture of my report design plus the row and column groups. These groups were created when I added them to the matrix and are not needed as far as what I can tell for my report:

[image]

Comment: try setting `Hide Duplicates` property to 'False' on the cell .

Comment: I get this error when I try that: "The value ‘False’ of the HideDuplicates property of the text box ‘DeviceSN’ is invalid. This value is the name of a group or dataset over which to apply the hiding: it should either be the name of a group containing the current group or, to hide duplicates over the entire dataset, the name of the current dataset."

Comment: Sorry I was doign it from, memory. Without seeing the report design it's hard to tell but can you put all cells at the detail level and don't use grouping, just sorting?

Comment: That's been my issue. When adding static columns to my matrix it automatically puts them all into row groups. I've tried to get rid of them but they won't budge.

Comment: Also, this answer gives a different approach but might be easy to adopt. AGain, tricky to tell withotu seeing the design.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868064/ssrs-repeat-tablix-left-most-row-group-value-on-each-row

Comment: If you are just adding columns at the detail level, right-click a detail level cell then just do Insert Column/Right (or left)

Comment: Still have the same issue with cells being merged.

Comment: Edit your question and show your report design otherwise it's all guesswork. Include the row groups (and column groups if applicable) in the screen shot

Comment: Added another picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not doing any calcuations on hte row gorups, there is no need for them.

Delete **all but one** of the row groups by right-clicking the rowgroup in the Row Groups pane at the bottom of the screen and choosing `Delete Group`. If prompted, choose `Delete Group Only`, otherwise it will delete the associated columns too.

When you noly have one group left, right-click it and choose `Group Properties` and delete the group expression, this will change it to be a details style group.

Make sure the `Hide Duplicate` expression is back to default (blank or None) in case you changed it earlier.

That should work. I replicated a similar scenario to your and the above step did the trick.

You will *probably* also need to go back to your group properties and set the sorting options to ensure data is sorted correctly.

Comment: does it matter which group I leave? Like should it be the outer most parent or something?

Comment: I tried the above but it ended up merging all my unpivoted cells together.

Comment: It doesn't matter which group you leave, basically we want to end up with a single detail group with no grouping defined. I'm not sure what you mean by "merging all unpivoted cells"... You could always just delete the matrix and start again but don't drag fields onto the design surface, just set the first column by choosing a field in the cell's drop down then right-click and add column right, set this field and repeat, only drag your column pivot field to the design so it will create the column group for you.

Comment: I'm adding the columns left of the matrix, could that be the problem? I'm referring to the matrix part as my pivoted cells, while the static columns are the ones giving me an issue.

Comment: I've tried it the way you suggested an remade the matrix. This merged all the cells in their columns. Is there a way to just specify that the cells will be unmerged?

Comment: As we don't seem to be getting anywhere we can try to take this to a private chat. I'll see if I get time to build a simple RDL based on what I think you are asking for and send that over chat. I'm in the UK. I'll start a chat room around 1pm your time (6pm here) tomorrow. https://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not Necessary! I actually found the answer in that link you posted earlier. I need to add the columns starting from the value cell. This doesn't create any groups and won't merge the cells. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it sorted out in the end.