# Displaying duplicate values in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, duplicates

I am trying to show duplicates in an SSRS report but it keeps displaying the format like this:

```
Order   Item
 111    567
        789
        567
 222    789
        345
        521
```

Whereas, im looking for it to be like this:

```
Order   Item
 111    567
 111    789
 111    567
 222    789
 222    345
 222    521
```

I can only assume this is something to do with the grouping. It is currently being grouped by order and item because i want to display both.

I have tried all the answers here inlcluding (changing the hideduplicates column and adding a sub group) but i still cant seem to fix it and get the output i want

"https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f37b8965-b4ca-471c-ae24-f85b8176d51e/how-to-show-duplicates-in-reports?forum=sqlreportingservices"

Has anyone got any other ideas?

Comment: Take out grouping and just have a flat result set?

Comment: *Why* are you grouping on both values?  Are there additional columns in the table?  If you just need both these columns to show all values, as Tab says, just remove the grouping altogether.

Comment: Take a look at this.  It's a bit hackey, but it works:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868064/ssrs-repeat-tablix-left-most-row-group-value-on-each-row

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Order textbox and go to properties, Under Other set Hide Duplicates to False.[image: HideDuplicates]

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Visual Studio, so the options available to me might differ from yours, but my solution is this:  In your report layout, in the General properties tab for the Order group, add Item to the Group expressions list.  Since Item is more granular than Order, the Order value should repeat for each row.