# SSRS: repeat tablix row group value on each row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I already consulted [SSRS: repeat tablix left-most row group value on each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868064/ssrs-repeat-tablix-left-most-row-group-value-on-each-row) but didn't get quite the answer I need (I'm open to get corrected).

I've got the issue that I need the group value repeated in an Excel export but also need a total row after the group value changes. So my table is built up like this:

```
                            [values1] [values2] [TOTAL by group2]
[group1] [group2] [group3]  ###.##    ####.## 
                  [TOTAL]   ###.##    ####.##   ####.##
```

And my expected result should be:

```
                            Hours Jan  Hours Feb  TOTAL by Person
Categrory1  Person1  Task1  5.5        4.5
            Person1  Task2  3.0        7.0
            Person1  TOTAL  8.5       11.5        20.0
            Person2  Task3  1.0        0.0
            Person2  Task4  2.0        0.0
            Person2  TOTAL  3.0        0.0         3.0
Catergory2  Person3  Task1  .....
```

But what I get now is:

```
                            Hours Jan  Hours Feb  TOTAL by Person
Categrory1  Person1  Task1  5.5        4.5
                     Task2  3.0        7.0
                     TOTAL  8.5       11.5        20.0
            Person2  Task3  1.0        0.0
                     Task4  2.0        0.0
                     TOTAL  3.0        0.0         3.0
Catergory2  Person3  Task1  .....
```

What leads to the problem, that users aren't able to filter by group2 (person) in Excel.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Simply don't put a row group on Person?

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for your comment! Well I guess I need that row group to get those tasks assigned to person correctly?

Comment: Remove group, it will ask you to remove only column, and again add person column before task

Comment: @Manoj thanks for your reply. I think I wasn't able to make my problem clear. I need to repeat the value but also need the grouping on person to get the total value. Removing the group (already tried) leads to alternating the total row with the tasks per person. So I don't get the totals per person but by task. Otherwise I get totals by catergory but not by person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to remove the `Person` column without removing the group. Then, right-click the header of the `Task` column to insert a column on the left ("inside the group") and let the person's name display in that column.

Comment: thanks. I already solved the issue, but this is exactly what I have done. Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  When you post a question and then come up with an answer on your own, post it as an answer so that anyone else who has the same question can benefit from your wisdom.

Comment: Thanks @FrankBall well that was exactly what I was up to when coming back to my question here, but Wolfgang was faster ;)