# SSRS export to Excel: Row group filters only show (Blank)

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that has several row groups ('Account No.', 'name', 'MAR Type') as well as row visibility toggled by the value 'Bill Date'. When I export the report to Excel and try to filter on the grouped columns, the only option that shows up is '(Blanks)' I have to make all the rows visible for filtering to work.

Is there any way to get the column values for the grouped rows to show to show up under filtering?

[image: example Excel report]

Comment: You need to change the report field so it repeats values where they are duplicated (e.g. Account No.). A bit messy in the SSRS, but would filter ok In Excel,

Comment: (Hide Duplicates setting on the textbox in question)

Comment: I tried hiding duplicates, but it has not changed the issue. There are no duplicates in the columns since they are row groups.

Comment: OK. There is this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868064/ssrs-repeat-tablix-left-most-row-group-value-on-each-row

Comment: Got it figured out. I re-added the parents groups of 'Account No', 'name', 'MAR Type' but with a header row this time. This is allowing their values to show up when running a filter in Excel.